# linux search a pattern and print its count

Tags: linux, shell, count, grep, command

In the following  i am trying to grep all the pattern  of geoIs.My question is how can i list different values of of geoIs along with it count

ex:

```
GeoIs:"Paramount","sumthing else"
GeoIs:"undefined","sumthing else"
GeoIs:"undefined","sumthing else"
GeoIs:"178","sumthing else"
GeoIs:"178","sumthing else"
and many more
...
...
```

Result expected:

```
GeoIs:"Paramount" 1
GeoIs:"undefined" 2
GeoIs:"178" 2
```

command

`zcat file.gz | grep -P '"geoIs":".*?.undefined*?"' | sort -u -T.|wc -l`

EDIT1:

GEOIS is found int he following string

```
  012-10-02 09:32:45{"e":{"ec":100001,"st":1349170352455,"bd":"Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.4%20(KHTMf01f02008592~rt%2366.657~rv%2366.228~as%2317~st%231349170293955~cat%231349170352431~sp%23as~c%2334~pat%231349128562942","smplCookie":"undefined","geoIPAddress":"122.107.154.58","geoCountry":"australia","geoCity":"Vermont","geoRegion":"Victoria","geoPostalCode":"undefined","geoLatitude":"undefined","geoLongitude":"undefined","geoMetro":"0","geoArea":"0","geoIs"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return a frequency table, use

```
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

For the sample data you provided, I'd use

```
zcat file.gz | cut -f1 -d, | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

zcat file.gz | grep -o '"searchstring":"[^"]*"'| sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: but sorry its not always the first field.it is spread over..Will edit the input in the question.Please have a look

Comment: And There are 10000 rows like mentioned in EDIT1 with different values

Comment: Then use `grep -o '"geoIsp":"[^"]*"'` instead of the `cut` part.

Comment: k m testing it will let u know

Answer (score 1):

an awk alternative:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]++;}END{for(x in a)if(x)print x,a[x]}' file


kent$  echo 'GeoIsp:"Paramount","sumthing else"
GeoIsp:"undefined","sumthing else"
GeoIsp:"undefined","sumthing else"
GeoIsp:"178","sumthing else"
GeoIsp:"178","sumthing else"
'|awk -F, '{a[$1]++;}END{for(x in a)if(x)print x,a[x]}'
GeoIsp:"Paramount" 1
GeoIsp:"undefined" 2
GeoIsp:"178" 2
```